# How do I see commit history of a user in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

We use Azure DevOps with TFVCS and I would like to see commit history of a user. How do I do it in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the repository
2. Select `Changesets`
3. Click the filter button and select the user in the `Author` dropdown

[image: Filter changesets by Author Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Rest API to get the Changests list of a specific user.

[Changesets - Get Changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changesets?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.author={email}&api-version=6.0
```

Result:

[image]